# Im trying to use another python file inside a different one and my function isnt passing numbers

Tags: python

File 1:

```
from tkinter import *
import randomnumgenerator as rng

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width='300', height='300')
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_rectangle(rng.generate_number(-10, 10), rng.generate_number(-10, 10), 200, 200, fill='red')

root.mainloop()
```

File 2:

```
import random

def generate_number(min_number, max_number):
    random_number = random.randint(min_number,max_number)
```

This is my error
Exception has occurred: TclError
wrong # coordinates: expected 0 or 4, got 2
File "main.py", line 9, in 
canvas.create_rectangle(rng.generate_number(-10, 10), rng.generate_number(-10, 10), 200, 200, fill='red')

Comment: At the end of the function, you have to return the value so that when you call a function, it will output the value as a result of executing the function. So: `return random_number`. Voting to close the question as a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have the same problem when you put in one file - so it has nothing to do with importing.

You have to use `return` in function `generate_number()`

```
def generate_number(min_number, max_number):
    return random.randint(min_number,max_number)
```

and then you can get result from function and assign to variables

```
x = rng.generate_number(-10, 10)
y = rng.generate_number(-10, 10)
canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, 200, 200, fill='red')
```

or use directly in other function

```
canvas.create_rectangle(rng.generate_number(-10, 10), rng.generate_number(-10, 10), 200, 200, fill='red')
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import random

# --- functions ---

def generate_number(min_number, max_number):
    return random.randint(min_number,max_number)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width='300', height='300')
canvas.pack()

#x = generate_number(-10, 10)
#y = generate_number(-10, 10)
#canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, 200, 200, fill='red')

canvas.create_rectangle(generate_number(-10, 10), generate_number(-10, 10), 200, 200, fill='red')

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

`wrong # coordinates: expected 0 or 4, got 2` means that `create_rectangle()` didn't get the 2x2=4 numbers as coordinates.

As @Delrius Euphoria points out, you forgot to actually return the random numbers from `generate_number()`. By default, Python has this function return `None` instead. tkinter.Canvas notices that its two first params are `None`. So what you did was:

```
canvas.create_rectangle(None, None, 200, 200, fill="red")
```

:-)